# How to get the version number of an application from the binary file?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, g++, elf

I am building a Qt/C+ application on Linux for some embedded devices and i would like to read the version of the app from the binary ELF file. The binary is not stripped and compiled with GCC.

Is there a way to build an executable file that can be simply read by some others programs to get the version of the application ?

Thanks.

Comment: [ELFIO - C++ library for reading and generating ELF files](http://elfio.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Every application developer will have different way of recording the application version in the application binary so it might be a long shot to read all the binary file looking for the string or number in the ELF file for the version info.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to build an executable file that can be simply read by some others programs to get the version of the application ?

Can this be done? Absolutely!

Should this be done? Probably not.

One of the easier ways to do this: put the application version into a text string, and use `__attribute__((section("my_app_version")))` to locate this string in a special section of your choice. [Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes).

Observe that `readelf -x.my_app_version` can extract this string.

Now all you have to do is replicate what `readelf` does: read ELF file header to locate sections, then read appropriate section. It would take non-trivial amount of code, something a skilled person could do in a few hours, or faster if one is willing to use helper libraries, such as [libelf](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libelf).

So why shouldn't you do this?

Since you are building an embedded system, at some point you likely create filesystem image to be flashed into the device.

Just before that final step of creating the filesystem, put a text file into it, containing all the relevant version info. For example, if you are putting `app1` and `app2` into the image, you could do something like this:

```
VERSIONS=/tmp/rootfs/etc/VERSIONS
rm -f $VERSIONS
echo BuiltBy=$(whoami)@$(hostname)  >> $VERSIONS
echo BuiltOn=$(date) >> $VERSIONS
echo App1=$(/tmp/build/bin/app1 --version) >> $VERSIONS
echo App2=$(/tmp/build/bin/app2 --version) >> $VERSIONS
```

Now any program running on the device can trivially find appropriate version info without having to extract it from the binary.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. Indeed, i create a fs at some point and i am trying to reduce the amount of extra scripts or files related to software management, especially if those datas could be extracted directly from the binary.

Comment: @Scab "reduce extra scripts" only makes sense if you reduce overall complexity. Adding non-trivial amount of C code that can crash at runtime to remove trivial shell script that can't fail makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

Some qt application show version, if you run it with command line arg `--version`, for example

```
$ kate --version
kate 15.12.3
```

Comment: this is only happening when the app is developed to read/accept commandline args, has nothing to do with QT and Qt is by default not providing this information.